# Flutter using Listview.builder with provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

How can i use `Listview.builder` with `provider`? I trying to access the data from other widgets. By using `Provider.of`

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final data = snapshot.data[index];
    return Provider.value(
      value: (_) => data,
      child: const ReportWidget(),
    );
  },
);

class ReportWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReportWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final reportData = Provider.of<ReportModel>(context);
    print(reportData);
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And what you get after trying to access it? please show us the result so, somebody can answer your result. Most people can't do mindreading because most people are ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this to get data from Provider:

```
final reportData = Provider.of<ReportModel>(context).listName;
```

You have to specify the data member or method to correctly access data.

Answer (score 0):

first try correct this line

```
 final reportData = Provider.of<ReportModel>(context, listen: false).listName;
```

for using listview builder with provider on other widget you can pass  reportData

```
final reportData  = context.watch<ReportModel>();
```

from widget 1 to widget 2 using constructor to avoid error caused by context of listview builder